# Why I getting inf value in my calculations with numpy and python

Tags: python, numpy, math

In my calculations I get infinite values and following error:

> ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for > dtype('float64').

The problem starts when I wanted the log of some of the columns in the data frame.
I believe the value and floating point gets really big after log. Then I rounded the value to one decimal point.
The problem still is there although it worked with most of the columns.

e.g.

```
df['log_tweets_reply'] = np.round(np.log(df['tweets'] * df['reply']), 1)
```

So how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure it's inf and not `NaN` ?, Also what about log(0) ? Maybe you're doing log(0).

Comment: I'm absolutely sure its `inf`.
log(0). Yesssss. You are right... there are some 0 in a data frame and it computes log(0).

Comment: as a quick fix, first try to do `np.log(df['tweets'] * df['reply'] + 1)`. If it works, you can now decide how you want to fix it, either the + 1, or make a special function that returns what ever you want if it's log(0) ..

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dataset contained a few zeros, and I didn't notice. and I was computing the log of 0 which the result is infinity.

Thanks to Eran Moshe.

Answer (score 1):

[np.log1p](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.log1p.html) should help you with *log*.

I would also suggest to do `df.isnull().sum()` for checking empty values.